# Position function not always returning an answer even with no apparent problems

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, numerics, sorting

I'm having some problems with `Position`.

Sometimes it will give an empty list instead of the actual position of the element I am looking for when that element is specified through some other code, but will return the correct position when the element is specified directly as a number as in the minimum working example below.

```
data = {{0.1, 0.0001683}, {0.2, 0.00035754}, {0.3, 0.00056711}, {0.4, 
   0.00078986}, {0.5, 0.0010333}, {0.6, 0.0010333}, {0.7, 
   0.0015758}, {0.8, 0.0018738}, {0.9, 0.0022054}, {1., 
   0.0025706}, {1.1, 0.0029788}, {1.2, 0.0034366}, {1.3, 
   0.0039831}, {1.4, 0.0046433}, {1.5, 0.0055203}, {1.6, 
   0.0068061}, {1.7, 0.010939}, {1.8, 0.031246}, {1.9, 0.054948}, {2.,
    0.076556}, {2.1, 0.098521}, {2.2, 0.12551}, {2.3, 0.1585}, {2.4, 
   0.1921}, {2.5, 0.22544}, {2.6, 0.25798}, {2.7, 0.28992}, {2.8, 
   0.32051}, {2.9, 0.35095}, {3., 0.38104}}

interpol = Interpolation[data];

q = FindRoot[interpol[x] == 0.159, {x, 2.9}][[1, 2]]
(*2.3015*)

xlow = Floor[q, 0.1]
(*2.3*)

Position[data[[All, 1]], xlow]
(*{}*)

Position[data[[All, 1]], 2.3]
(*{{23}}*)
```

When running *Mathematica* 8 on Windows XP, this code returns `{}` for the first output and `{{23}}` for the second.

This type of error is mentioned in the Possible Issues section of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html#) for `Position` in v8 and v9, but no advice is given.

```
In[1] := Position[Range[-1, 1, 0.05], 0.1]
Out[1] = {}
```

I thought this might be a precision or representation issue (i.e., `2.3` vs `23/10`), so I've tried using `N` everywhere to get around the issue, but with no success. Does anyone have a nifty work around or solution to this problem?

Comment: Would `Position[data[[All, 1]], Nearest[data[[All, 1]], xlow][[1]]]` be acceptable ?

Comment: It works so it most certainly would be acceptable! Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Since I believe the correct answer is to use `Chop` (see below), it's also worth pointing to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6994/245) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11542/245).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html) is looking for an *exact* match (pseudo-[`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html)), rather than a numeric one.
You will get the result you want with:

```
Position[data[[All, 1]], _?(# == xlow &)]
```

Or:

```
Position[data[[All, 1]], x_ /; x == xlow]
```

Generally you should use [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html) (short form `==`) any time you are trying to mach [`Real`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Real.html) numbers, to allow for small rounding errors.

Using the pattern `0 | 0.` is not sufficient;  See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5154/121) for examples.

---

For an excellent treatment of the problems of matching inexact numbers see:

[Instability in DeleteDuplicates and Tally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169506/618728)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Both of those do the job perfectly but I'm a bit confused by the structure you use in the first one. Wouldn't the `_?` return a `True` value instead of a numeric? The second structure I don't fully understand either as I don't see how `Position` knows to loop over `x` and compared each term. There is obviously more functionality built in than I appreciate

Comment: @fizzics Both `_?(# == xlow &)` and `x_ /; x == xlow` are *patterns*, which is what `Position` needs as a second argument.  `_?testfunction` is a pattern for any single expression for which `testfunction` yields `True` when applied. `x_ /; expr` is a pattern for any single expression, which we *locally* name `x`, for which `expr` evaluates to `True`; if `x` appears in `expr` the *local* definition is used.  Read the documentation for `Pattern`, `PatternTest`, and `Condition`, then see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121).  Return with any further questions.

Answer (score 8):

One alternative approach that is very powerful when dealing with approximate real numbers hasn't been mentioned yet: use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html) or [`Threshold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Threshold.html).

These two functions are intended for just the type of situations you describe, so I would always try them *first*:

In your example, this simple command works:

```
Position[Chop[data[[All, 1]] - xlow], 0]
```

> `{{23}}`

Instead of finding `xlow`, I reformulated the problem so that you find `0` in the list of *differences* with `xlow`.

Comment: Excellent recommendation.  Numeric methods are almost always faster.