# How does mathematica decide what `x_` is in `MemberQ[list,x_/;(x==#)]&/@list`

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test

Consider the following code:

```
list={1,2}
MemberQ[list, x_ /; (x == #)] & /@ list
```

This gives `{True,True}`

`MemberQ[list,form]`  means that an element of List matches `form`,

> But how does mathematica know what to put for the pattern `x_`?

Asked differently, I view the above `MemberQ` as doing the following:

- MemberQ is a pure function as input above
- Map (/@) applies list to the MemberQ (pure) function

  - This means that Map evaluates MemberQ with each element of `list` in place of `#`
- **What part of the code tells mathematica what to use for the named pattern `x_`??**. (in other words, how does mathematica know what $x$ is when checking `x==#` is true or not)

I thought maybe `Map` was applying the list elements to both `#` and `x_`, but

```
f[x_, #] & /@ {5}
```

gives `{f[x_,5]}`

---

Edit:
An example of where this construct is potentially relevant: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15909/34646)

---

Edit 2: I think maybe this is what is happen:

First let us look at `MemberQ[list,x_]`. This will give `True` For (almost?) list. What is this doing? This is saying does `list` match the form of `Pattern[x,Blank[]]`. Well, `Pattern[x,Blank[]]`, is just any expression, so yes list matches.

Now let us consider `MemberQ[list,x_/;(x==#)]`. This is asking whether list matches patterns that are an expression AND have `(x==#)`. Well, if `#` is an expression, it will match (the condition will be satisfied), and since we are doing `/@list`, we are asking if expressions of the form in `list` match elements in `list`, which is true.

Comment: Wrapping `Trace` around the computation might give some information about the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think perhaps you are seeking or misunderstanding the function of `/;` which is shorthand for [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html).  You write: "how does mathematica know what x is when checking x==# is true or not."  The value bound to the pattern `x_` is substituted into the right hand side of `/;` where `x` appears, in the manner of rules or function definitions.

Compare:

```
f[x_] := Print[something[x]]

f /@ {1, 2, 3}

MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x_ /; Print[something[x]]]

Cases[{1, 2, 3}, x_ :> Print[something[x]]]
```

These all print:

> something[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121)
>
> something[2]
>
> something[3]

---

Preserved for reference, you wrote:

> I will try rephrasing: **what is "the value bound to the pattern"** in the 3rd and 4th lines of your code? I look at the second line and I see map that says "hey, apply `{1,2,3}` to `f`. But in lines 3 and 4 I don't see what part of the commands binds a value to `x` (I understand that the value bound to `x` is substituted in the right hand side, but I don't understand why (in your lines 3 and 4) 1,2, and 3 are being bound to `x`)

Both [`MemberQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html) and [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) have an implicit *levelspec*<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121)</sup> of {1}, as does [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).  Writing these out in explicit form:

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x_ /; Print[x], {1}];
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, x_ :> Print[x], {1}];
Map[Print, {1, 2, 3}, {1}];
```

A different *levelspec* can be used for each, e.g. `{0, 1}` to include the complete expression:

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x_ /; Print[x], {0, 1}];
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, x_ :> Print[x], {0, 1}];
Map[Print, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 1}];
```

Each function also supports the [`Heads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) option.

Observe that `List` in `List[1, 2, 3]` is itself a level one component:

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x_ /; Print[x], {1}, Heads -> True];
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, x_ :> Print[x], {1}, Heads -> True];
Map[Print, {1, 2, 3}, {1}, Heads -> True];
```

(Printing omitted throughout to avoid cluttering this post.)

Comment: I will try rephrasing: **what is "the value bound to the pattern"** in the 3rd and 4th lines of your code? I look at the second line and I see map that says "hey, apply `{1,2,3}` to `f`. But in lines 3 and 4 I don't see what part of the commands binds a value to `x` (I understand that the value bound to `x` is substituted in the right hand side, but I don't understand why (in your lines 3 and 4) 1,2, and 3 are being bound to `x`)

Comment: @majmun Got it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is applying the test to each element of the list.  Consider this:

```
list = {1, 2}
MemberQ[list, x_ /; (x + # == 4)] & /@ list
```

> {False, True}

When `x` and `#` are both 2 the `x_` pattern as 2 is tested in `MemberQ`.  Otherwise the `x_` pattern is `False`. I.e. `MemberQ[list, False]` which in turn yields `False`.

In the case of your code

```
MemberQ[list, x_ /; (x == #)] & /@ list
```

it seems unlikely the test would ever yield `False`, but then again strange cases can be produced:

```
list = {a = 1, Unevaluated[1 + a]};
MemberQ[list, x_ /; (x == #)] & /@ list
```

> {True, False}

I.e. The `x` pattern remains unevaluated while `#` evaluates in the map, so

`Unevaluated[1 + a] == 2` tests `False` and then `MemberQ` does too.

Finally,

The constructions in the "potentially relevant" [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15909/363) you mention are these:

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, _?(# == 2 &)]
```

and

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x_ /; x == 2]
```

both of which are equivalent, and evaluate to `True`.  Your actual case is like the latter, with a pure function `#` added for the map.

```
MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x_ /; x == #] & /@ {2, 4}
```

> {True, False}

Comment: But why are `x` and `#` being taken to be the same?  I realize that `x_` stands for any expression, and we call it x, but when I look at the code It looks to me like it needs to be told two things: what is the expression `x_`, and what is `#`. Obviously this is not the case

Comment: Using the `x_` pattern just facilitates a test on `#`, so it is testing itself.  And its value is each item in `list`, taken in turn.